# SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when run nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, syntax-error

When I run this `nestjs` code, I encounter an error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

what is the reason?

```
import {Controller, Get, Bind, Req, Post} from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('cats')
export class catsController {
    @Post()
    create() {
        return "this is a action 1ss"
    }
    @Get()
    @Bind(Req())
    findAll(request) {
        return "this is a action";
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows ‍‍‍```@Controller``` error.

Comment: How are you running the project?

Comment: In Webstorm with node :|

Comment: What command are you using to run it?

Comment: ```node projectName```

Comment: Well that's not going to work since decorators in plain JavaScript rely on some sort of build tool. Are you using the NestJS CLI?

Comment: Yes ```npm i -g @nestjs/cli```

Comment: So why not use the CLI to run the project

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Have you read the overview and tutorial on NestJS' site yet? [Here](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/overview) you can see what the CLI can do. Scroll down a little and see that you can use `npm run start:dev` to start the project.

Answer (score 12):

If facing the following problem:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

Update `node` to version >=16, since the above syntax is not supported below that version

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using JavaScript, not Typescript, you need to have a babel config like the following

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

And then use `babel-node` instead of `node` so that `babel` can properly interpret the decorators.

[The docs even mention this on the getting started page](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps#language)

> Nest takes advantage of the latest language features, so to use it with vanilla JavaScript we need a [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) compiler.

Comment: I did this but it still can't interpret the decorators.

Comment: What babel plugins do you have installed? There are several required. [Take a look at the javascript-starter](https://github.com/nestjs/javascript-starter)